# Why my app only allow download for people on Organization?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

It's been a while since the last time I published an app to the Google Play Store, there are many changes so I don't know if I missed any step.
Now, I am using an account of my company, it's organization account. I did publish the app but only people using the company email access to the app in the store.
In the dashboard, it already shows that the production is active:
[image]
[image]
App content is all done
[image]

The production page looks fine
[image]

The Google Play link is accessible but only for company email, otherwise, it shows not found page
[image]

Do I need to check on other things or am I missing any step?
or does Google have any page that shows us the app's status, or what else do we need to do to publish the app?

Thank you

Edit 1: App availability is set as Published
[image]

- What I am concerned is about the Managed google play, does it affect the publish?
  [image]

Comment: What format does your link look like?

Comment: like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached the support team and already got the explanation about this. Thank you everyone.
Here are some steps that you have to do if you are facing it:

- If the Managed Google play is on, we can not turn it off
- We have to turn off Managed Google play by going to your Users and permissions page, you can uncheck the box of Managed Google Play and save the changes.
- Create a new app with a new packgage name

Hope that it will help you if you are also facing this issue. Thank for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Check for App availability in Setup -> Advanced Settings, maybe it's unpublished

[image]

Comment: I did it. But it still :(

Comment: Did you turn on Managed Publishing? Look at the Publishing overview tab to see any pending changes.

Comment: Yes it on, 
"Changes that are ready to publish will appear here once they're approved by Google"

Comment: Well, I think we can wait 1 or 2 days for syncing data I guess. Or ask for Google support.

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled Managed Google Play.

This means you have set only the people in the selected organization to see the app.

On the page from the screenshot you have provided, unselect the organisation (under where it says `Only these organizations can access your app`) and save your changes. After this change all people should be able to see the app.

[image]

Comment: I reached the support team, and they said I have to create a new app, this setting can't be changed